# Override FileStorage.save behavior in Flask

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I want to push files to a storage service with the `FileStorage.save` method. In Django, I would change the storage backend to accomplish this. Is there a way to change what `FileStorage.save` does in a Flask application?

Answer (score 1):

Werkzeug does not provide for different behavior in `FileStorage.save`.

You may patch the method to change its behavior globally.

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage

def save(self, dst, buffer_size=16384):
    # do something else with the self.stream

FileStorage.save = save
```

You may also use an extension such as [Flask-Storage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Storage), which creates a similar interface to Django's storage backends, and would be used instead of `save`.